# A subset of our services were/was? Grammar

Tags: grammar

I am unsure  of whether it should be  *was* or *were*.

The *was/were* refers to the *subset* rather than *services*.  (which is obviously plural)

So I think the question becomes: is it *subset were* or *subset was*?

Or maybe my reasoning is faulty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Subset* could be either singular or plural. [This COCA search](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=34655644) shows 3 out of 15 uses of *subset* with the verb "to be" were plural uses ("were" or "are"), and 12 were singular uses.

Here, *subset* is a collective noun, and you can use a plural verb when members of the collective are acting as individuals, this is similar to *group* ("This group of surgeons have been operating every weekend their entire careers") or *staff* ("Our staff work hard to meet their goals and deadlines"). In British English, collective nouns taking plural verbs is more common, but they are not always ungrammatical in American English.

Comment: Two of those plural matches are "*A total of 56% of the teenagers in the subset were girls*" and "*Four of the 10 items on the frustration subset were implicated*". In both these cases, *subset* is singular. Only one of those matches could be read as having a plural form of *subset*, "*The largest subset are counties with large numbers of racial or ethnic populations*".

Comment: @p.s.w.g Indeed, though the first example is one of plural "total", another collective noun singular in form but plural in construction.

Comment: Yep, you're correct. +1 for extending the discussion to collective nouns, which seems to be the confusion here.

Comment: Thanks. Categorising subset as a collective  noun helps clarify my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You have rightly decided that the subject of the verb is *subset*. That is singular, so the verb is *was*.